# How to fill this type of gradient in circle in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

How can I fill this type of gradient in a circle?

This is my sample:

[image]

Comment: Hi Chirag! To be able to help we need to know what you have tried, and why it didn't work. The image, to me, looks like three separate gradients (one for each part of the shape).

Comment: @Yisela is right, you would need to make one shape with a gradient fill and arrange three instances of it around the circle.

Answer (score 2):

As comments elude to, you need to create 3 separate shapes, each with a gradient at a different angle. This is *not* a single gradient. Once the 3 shapes are aligned, you end up with something similar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible (or hardly possible) to crrate such gradient style. And it is not a single circle. It must have segments and these gradients are adjusted to obtain this kind of style